# How to make items float outside of Jquery Dialogs

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I want to have a dialog that looks kinda like this:

[image: Dialog with items floating outside]

I thought this approach would work but I guess I was wrong:

**JavaScript**

```
//Creates The Dialog
$('.ImageDialogDiv').dialog({
    position: [98, 223],
    resizable: false,
    //modal: true,   /* UNCOMMENT AFTER DEBUGGING */
    closeOnEscape: false,
    class: 'OverwriteDialogOverflow',
    title: $('#hiddenDialogElements').html(),
    open: function (event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }
});
```

**CSS**

```
  /*
  * Overrides hidden overflow
  */
 .OverwriteDialogOverflow
 {
     overflow: visible;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id = "dialogDiv" class = "ImageDialogDiv"></div>

<div id = "hiddenDialogElements">
    <button id = "hiddencloseButton">Close</button>
    <div id = "hiddenArrowButtons">
        <button class = "ArrowButtonDialogLeft" onclick = "ShowNextImage(-1)" ></button>
        <button class = "ArrowButtonDialogRight" onclick = "ShowNextImage(1)" ></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I attempt to move the arrows or close button off of the dialog, then get cut off and will not be visible. I though that adding `.OverwriteDialogOverflow` would take care of that.

Suggestions?

Comment: do you have an example we could look at?

Comment: I tried to get it to work, but I can never get anything in fiddle using jquery to work. If you can get the dialog to show up, then you can see that the close button is outside of it (not showing up. http://jsfiddle.net/U6w3K/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll edit this with more detail if/when you update the post, but what I would do is put the dialog and buttons in a container div with relative positioning, and use absolute positioning to place the buttons. Something like below...

HTML:

```
    <div id = "hiddenDialogElements">
        <button id = "hiddencloseButton">Close</button>
        <div id = "hiddenArrowButtons">
            <button class = "ArrowButtonDialogLeft" onclick = "ShowNextImage(-1)" ></button>
            <button class = "ArrowButtonDialogRight" onclick = "ShowNextImage(1)" ></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.OverwriteDialogOverflow { overflow: visible; }

#dialogContainer { position: relative; }

#hiddencloseButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    right: -15px;
}

#hiddenArrowButtons {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
}

.ui-dialog { overflow: visible; }
```

**Edit:** added .ui-dialog CSS as per comment

Comment: Would `relative` positioning on the buttons cause my issue? Thats how I position them all

Comment: Maybe. I guess it depends on the other CSS, especially for the dialog and the overlay. Do you have a live example on your site I could look at?

Comment: Using `position: absolute` allows you to set the position relative to the nearest non-static ancestor. In this case, setting the container `div` to `position: relative` means you can set the position of the buttons relative to that container.

Comment: I tried to use the `absolute` positioning but that didn't work. Let me figure out how to use this jsfiddle better. That will make it easier to see my problem

Comment: The issue was that I had to do this: `.ui-dialog { overflow: visible;}`. Add that in an edit and ill accept it

Comment: I had to use `.ui-dialog-content { overflow: visible; }` to get this working. Using jQuery UI 1.12.0

Answer (score 0):

For the close button to move outside I have written this code

```
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").css('background-image', 'url(../../images/closePopUpX.png)');
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").css('width','25');
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").css('height','25');
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").css('top','-7px');
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").css('right','-15px');
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").css('background-repeat','no-repeat');
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").css('background-position','center center');
                $(".ui-dialog").css('overflow','visible');
                $('.ui-icon').css('display','none');
```

in dialog create section.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom inline CSS and classes on the **open:** function call...

```
    $('#splash_screen_dialog').dialog({
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).css({
                'max-height': 500,
                'overflow-y': 'auto'
            }).addClass('dialog-overflow');
        }
    });
```