# Make an image float outside of jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery dialog where I want an image from inside of it appear to float outside of the dialog box.  I tried the solution located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115947/how-to-make-items-float-outside-of-jquery-dialogs) but it does not work for me.  All I see is a truncated image once it crosses over the border of the dialog window (or dialog titlebar), so I got rid of that solution from my code and started again from scratch.  My relevant code is now as follows:

jQuery:

```
$("#idForm").dialog();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="idForm" title="Identify">
    <img src='images/i_info.png' 
         alt="identify icon" 
         id='idFormIdentifyIcon' 
         style="position: relative; top: -20px; left: -20px; z-index: 999999" />
    ...other HTML here...
</div>
```

All I want is the image to float outside the dialog window.  Any tips?  I've tried both absolute and relative positing and both with and without "overflow: visible" on, as in the linked example.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115947/how-to-make-items-float-outside-of-jquery-dialogs ?

Comment: Maybe you are not giving us the complete code. Giving the div#idForm {position: relative;} and img#idFormIdentifyIcon {position: absolute; top: -20px; left: -20px;} should do the trick.

Comment: Make sure your `overflow` is `visible`. That should be the default, but you never know, something somewhere might be changing that... *EDIT: Sorry, just so your post script...*

Comment: @Rahul - Yes, that was the link I provided in the beginning of my question.  :)

Comment: @Jawad and agryson - Yes I did modify the CSS in the end. I left it out since I was starting over from scratch, so to speak. I left that detail out of my question though, so thanks for pointing it out as it's important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by placing my image in the titlebar of my dialog window (instead of in the main text below) and then following the rest of the instructions in the linked example at the beginning of my question.